# Is there a way to scroll up a particular div element in a webpage using selenium with PYTHON?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I could scroll down or up a whole web page but I am having trouble in scrolling a particular div element within the webpage

The thing is when I open a webpage like whatsapp web and within a particular chat containing the messages(which is particular div element),I want to scrape all the messages from the beginning of the chat ,but I could only scrape the messages which is in the view (the last few messages),So I want to scroll that particular div element to the top of the chat to scrape all the messages.
Can someone help me with this thing in PYTHON.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there are multiple ways using which you could scroll to particular element

**By using the move_to_element()**

```
 element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("_element_")

 action = ActionChains(driver)
 action.move_to_element(element).perform()
```

**By scrollIntoView()**

```
 element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("_element_")
 driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element)
```

For reference [check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34562095/scrollintoview-vs-movetoelement) [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible.
Let's say the element you need to scroll inside is `div_el`, it's locator is `xpath_locator` the code will be like this:

```
div_locator = "xpath_locator"
div_el = driver.find_element_by_xpath(div_locator)
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollTop = arguments[0].scrollHeight", div_el)
```

See more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38041974/selenium-scroll-inside-of-popup-div)